# How to describe the instantaneous speed of an object

Tags: present-tense

Consider that car X has a certain speed at the instant when passing point Y and that Formula Z calculates the speed.

I would like to know which of the sentences listed below I created is the best to describe the situation.

> 1. Formula Z calculates the speed of car X at the instant when it passes point
>      Y.
> 2. Formula Z calculates the speed of car X that appears at the instant when the car passes point Y.
> 3. Formula Z calculates the speed of car X passing point Y.

I think the first one has the possibility of being misunderstood that Formula Z **calculates at the instant when**...

I think the second one is the best, but may be awkward.

I am not sure whether the third one makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. is formally ambiguous, but you'd have to be really perverse to misconstrue it.
2. is very unclear. "Appear" is not something you would normally use of speed, and I find it a garden path sentence, because I think it is the car that appears until I meet "the car".
3. is the best of the three. I would say "as it passes" rather than "passing" though.

Comment: You recommend using "as", but I first couldn't understand the difference between "when" and "as".  After consulting my dictionary in detail, I found the usage of "as" clause that can modify the noun in front of it.  Is my understanding correct?

Comment: No. In this use, "as" is syntactically interchangeable with "when", and very nearly identical in meaning. I cannot work out why "as" feels more natural to me than "when" there, but it does. "When" would still be OK, just not as natural.

Comment: I found the same usage of "when" as the "as". I understand. Thanks.